# Haskell FFi with c2hs: Better out-marshalling of structs

Tags: c, haskell, struct, ffi, c2hs

Suppose you have a C API provides that provides a C struct

```
typedef struct A {
    int i;
    float f;
} A;
```

and a function that populates it:

```
void getA(A* a);
```

For example, this could be a getter for some information from the innards of the C API.

In Haskell the C struct would be mirrored by

```
data A = A {
    i :: Int,
    f :: Float
}
```

The `Storable` instance is

```
instance Storable A where
    sizeOf    _ = {#sizeof  A #}
    alignment _ = {#alignof A #}
    peek p = ...
    poke p x = ...
```

Peek and poke are business as usual with the `{#get...#}` and `{#set #}` pragmas processed by c2hs.

The Haskell function `getA :: IO A` should be something like

```
{#fun unsafe getA as getA {alloca- `A' peek*} -> `()'#}
```

except this doesn't work because c2hs creates this binding:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "include/A.h getA"
    _getA'_ :: Ptr () -> IO ()
```

It has `Ptr ()` as first argument. This can be sorted out by

```
{#fun unsafe getA as getA {allocaA- `A' peekA*} -> `()'#}

peekA :: Ptr () -> IO A
peekA = peek . castPtr

allocaA :: (Ptr () -> IO a) -> IO a
allocaA f = alloca $ \(p :: Ptr A) -> f (castPtr p)
```

The `allocaA` is important because it ensures that memory for an `A` is allocated instead of memory for just a `()` if `alloca` were used.

Although this works it is somewhat tedious and you have guaranteed segfaults if you ever forget to write `allocaXYZ` instead of just `alloca`. (I just saw a good amount of time being spent on tracking down one such error.)

I expected to find a `{#fun...#}` incantation that produces

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "include/A.h getA"
    _getA'_ :: Ptr A -> IO ()
```

from which all else would follow naturally (note the `Ptr A` instead of `Ptr ()`). But as far as I can tell there's only the `{allocXYZ- 'XYZ' peekXYZ*}` route.

So the question is: **Can this be done in a better way using `c2hs`?**

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `{#pointer ...#}` hooks?  Since you're not treating A like an opaque pointer (i.e. `i` and `f` are accessible normally and the `Storable` instance is written explicitly), you'll want to use the arrow form:

```
{#pointer *A as APtr -> A#}
```

At that point, you still have to use the `alloca`/`peek` functions to marshal `A`, but your first, ideal `{#fun ...#}` hook should work as written.  (You wind up ignoring the `APtr` type; it shows up in the generated code, but it's not necessary in the `*.chs` file.)

Also note that you need to add that pointer definition to every file `A` is used in; even if you export `APtr` from one primary file, you still need to add `{#pointer *A as APtr -> A nocode#}` everywhere you use it.